# InflateException because of style attr on Floating Action Button on Android 5.0 +

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am repeating this project https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/FloatingActionButton_Animation_Project and it uses standard `Floating Action Button`.

In **main.xml** layout :

```
...
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/calls_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fragment_calls_swipeRefreshLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:layout_behavior="com.my.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
        />

    <include layout="@layout/fab_add_layout" />
...
```

Additional Buttons **fab_add_layout.xml**:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_group_add_black_24dp"
    style="@style/MyAppTheme.SubFab"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_accounts"
    style="@style/MyAppTheme.SubFab"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_opportunities"
    style="@style/MyAppTheme.SubFab"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_leads"
    style="@style/MyAppTheme.SubFab"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

On the devices with Android 4.4 everything is working fine, but on higher versions starting from Lollipop I get an error:

```
Process: com.myfabs , PID: 11441
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:561)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:437)
at fi.lunni.mobileadvisor.ui.fragments.CallsListFragment_.onCreateView(CallsListFragment_.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1643)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1272)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1646)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:703)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1367)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:768)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:765)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:647)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:765)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:647)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5976)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2713)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18948)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2158)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1252)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1488)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1143)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6256)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:886)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:698)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:633)
```

After I took away `style` attribute everything is working fine. Here is my `style` :

```
<style name="MyAppTheme.SubFab">
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd" tools:targetApi="17">24dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">72dp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint" tools:targetApi="21">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom|right|end</item>
</style>
```

**Question** : Can you explain me the situation with this? Why does it happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a parent to your style, and don't use the `.` in your style name, it has a [precise meaning](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance).

Furthermore you should use `backgroundTint` rather than `android:backgroundTint`, because `FloatingActionButton` has its own `backgroundTint` attribute (whose behaviour is slightly different from `android:backgroundTint`), compatible also with API levels before 21:

```
<style name="SubFab" parent="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/sub_fab_rightMargin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd" tools:targetApi="17">@dimen/sub_fab_rightMargin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/sub_fab_bottomMargin</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom|right|end</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry but does not help, same problem

Comment: May you try to change `"android:backgroundTint"` in `"backgroundTint"` in your style? That backgroundTint is not the standard Android attribute, but the `FloatingActionButton`'s one. You should also delete `tools:targetApi="21"`, because that attribute (without `android:`) is also supported by previous API levels.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :)